# Property 'changeView' does not exist on type 'CalendarOptions'

Tags: angular

I'm using Full calendar V5 in angular, and in the dateClick i allways get the error on the changeView.
I want to click on a day, and switch the view to "timeGridDay".
my code is this:
"

```
dateClick: function(info) {
      if(info.view.type=="dayGridMonth"){
          this.changeView("timeGridDay",info.dateStr);
      }
    }
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `changeView` on the reference to the calendar object itself.

In the example below that would be named `calendar`

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });
```

This needs to be a global variable, not local to a setup function

So the code you want would be, in this case, would be

```
dateClick: function(info) {
      if(info.view.type=="dayGridMonth"){
          calendar.changeView("timeGridDay",info.dateStr);
      }
    }
```